# Как запустить pm2 в docker контейнере?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pm2

Пытаюсь упаковать мое node.js приложение в docker контейнер.
Вот мой dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i --only=prod
RUN npm i -g pm2
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 3333
CMD [ "pm2", "start server.js" ]
```

Создаю образ

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

запускаю контейнер

```
docker run --rm -it -p 3333:3333 myapp
```

При попытке создания контейнера в консоли появляется пространный хелп pm2,
потом сообщение

```
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/root/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[PM2] Command not found
```

потом продолжение хелпа.
Контейнер сразу удаляется.

Если создать контейнер без флага --rm, а потом зайти в него, то можно руками ввести команду `pm2 start server.js`, и приложение успешно запускается и начинает отвечать по сети (пока не выйдешь из контейнера).

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: гм. как запустить pm2 в docker контейнере? а главное, зачем? :)

Answer (score 1):

Собственно раз `Command not found`, решил помочь системе ее найти.
Узнал путь до бинарника с помощью `which pm2`, последнюю строчку заменил на

```
CMD [ "/usr/local/bin/pm2", "start server.js" ]
```

заработало.